# Проблемы с Core Data

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, coredata

Сразу после создания нового проекта под osx с включенной Core Data появились ошибки в AppDelegate.swift

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: import coredata я думаю должен помочь

Comment: import не помог, но только что нашел решение. Поменял название проекта. У меня оно было "CoreData"

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте код в виде текста, а не изображения.